# Is there a method to share a file across container with write & read access in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I just started exploring kubernetes concepts. I am using helm chart to do deployment of pod. Got stucked to solve the below problem. Anyone kindly help me to unblock this issue.

I have three containers, lets say A, B and C. container A is having a file => "/root/dir1/sample.txt". Otherwise I can prepare this file offline but needs to be mounted in all three containers. Container A and container C has a service running which will update that file. Container B has a service running which will read that file. so, I need this file to be shared across all the three containers.

Approach 1:
Using emptyDir volume, I tried mounting this file but it doesn't helped my case. Because when I use emptyDir I am losing all the files under dir1 which comes via container images. Also I don't want other files under dir1 to be shared across containers. In addition to that I need to mount the file as same directory structure "/root/dir1/sample.txt" instead of creating empty dir say "/root/dir2" as shared-data mount and copying sample.txt to dir2 as "/root/dir2/sample.txt". Reason is now mounting /root/dir2 in all three containers (file write happening in any container reflected in other containers). But this does not helped my case as my need is to mount the file as same directory structure "/root/dir1/sample.txt".

Approach 2:
Using configmap volume, I can mount the file "sample.txt" under dir1 as expected. But it is mounted as read-only filesystem and containers A and C are unable to write the file.

So above two approaches does not helped my case. It would be great if anyone help me on how to mount a file directly into containers with write access under same directory structure and shared across containers. Or any volume type available in kubernetes will help my case (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#cinder).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say you can prepare the file offline; can you `COPY` it into your Dockerfile, and do a normal build-and-deploy sequence when you need to update it?  Since Kubernetes is intrinsically a clustered environment "sharing files" doesn't usually work that well.

Comment: @David Maze Thanks for your response! But my case is the file can be prepared offline but the service running inside containers will write/update that file based on customers input. So I think build and deploy sequence won't help my case in actual.

Answer (score 5):

I think your best option is to use an emptyDir and an initContainer that mounts it to another path and copies the original files into it. Its not an uncommon pattern. See it in action in [rabbitmq cluster operator](https://github.com/rabbitmq/cluster-operator/commit/60b048fde7d7314801d34d051f88a7577640efdb).

That would look something like this in the pod:

```
(...)
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: shared-dir
      emptyDir: {}
  initContainers:
    - name: prepare-dir
      image: YOUR_IMAGE
      command:
        - sh
        - '-c'
        - 'cp /root/dir1 /tmp/dir1'
      volumeMounts:
        - name: shared-dir
          mountPath: /tmp/dir1/
  containers:
    - name: container-a
      image: YOUR_IMAGE
      volumeMounts:
        - name: shared-dir
          mountPath: /root/dir1/
    - name: container-b
      image: YOUR_IMAGE
      volumeMounts:
        - name: shared-dir
          mountPath: /root/dir1/
(...)
```

Comment: @chicovenancio Thanks for your response. But I just need a clarification to understand a bit clear. With the above mentioned approach, when we mount /root/dir1 as emptyDir, it will create an empty directory and the files coming via any other container under dir1 will be lost right? But I don't want it to be lost. What is the role of the tmp directory as shared one here? Also I don't want all the files under dir1 to be shared. Example if two text files say sample1 and certs present under dir1 and I don't want certs to get shared because certificates will be generated unique to each containers.

Comment: @anonymoususer volumes are different from their mount points (volumeMounts in kubernetes). Mounting a volume into a non-empty mount point does hide the contents of the mount point, which is why copying the files to the volume before its mounted into the shared directory is a good approach. By the time the initContainer finishes and the container-a starts the files inside the volume and on the mount point are the same.

Comment: @anonymoususer if you don't want to share the volume from container-a to container-b they should probably be in separate pods. But at least a separate volume per-container (they can all be shared by a single initContainer if the same image is necessary, with a more robust script. Or several initContainers for each image.),

Answer (score 0):

This is a read-write-many scenario and there are two ways I know that you can do this.

First, you can use an external mount (such as an NFS server) then mount that into your pod. If you don't have an NFS server of your own, you can use a managed NFS service such [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) on Google or [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) on AWS (note that this will incur a cost)

Second, you can install an NFS provisioner into the cluster such as [this one](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/kvaps/nfs-server-provisioner) which will generate a new `StorageClass` that you can use to generate a `PersistentVolume`, that is read-write-many capable and you can share that around your pods. This, while a cluster-native option, does have its own issues -- if the provisioner pod crashes or is evicted, the pods depending on the NFS mount will hang and then crash also, so YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let me check for first approach. But second approach is a volume mount as persistent one. I don't want the file content as persistent. Because whenever pod gets deleted and redeployed I want the file as fresh one with default values in it not the persistent one.

Comment: The only way I am aware you can get a RWM mount is via an NFS mount -- and that implies the state is shared. If you need to wipe the contents of the volume during a redeploy, and if you're using Helm, you can use a `pre-upgrade` hook: https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/ to do the wipe before the main upgrade and redeploy. But first try to decide and get the NFS working, then you can add the cleanup part.

Comment: I don't really see this a read-write-many scenario. To me the question is looking for multiple containers accessing the same volume, but not multiple pods.

Comment: For the clarification, I would say Container A and C will update the file under dir1 (write scenario) based on customer's action  and container B should be able to read the last updated ones (read scenario)